# Click on main text opens a new detail page on a card

Tags: accessibility, hyperlinks, psychology, experience, heuristics

I have a situation where I have a card as an element and it had primary Title, Sub title, and other texts and one secondary CTA.
The problem that I am facing is the click on the main title opens a new details page of this card but users aren't able to guess that there is a click on this card.
other things that I have thought is making card clickable but this, if I follow there are a lot of other elements that are clickable too, will this not make it very straining to users.
Is there any way that I can say user that there is one more click to view the details page of this card

[image]

Comment: do you have a little more hi fidelity mock? You could use color for the links, but it's hard to see from what you have here.

Answer (score 1):

#### You could start by making the affordances more clear.

You can use several options, which you can combine:

- use a **'Learn more'** or **'View details'** link. Don't make them guess. Tell them.
- Use color on your links.
- Underline your links.
- hover on card to bring out both color or underline.
- Separate your visual info (the logo) from the written content.
- Layout (the secondary CTA can shift out of the way).
- Size of the secondary CTA: you can make it a more subtle button if it's not as important as viewing the details.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIb5o9.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

It's hard to tell from your mockup, so my card depiction might be a little simplified. You seem to have placeholders for a lot of text.

Normally cards contain a title, some logo / pictorial info and a description, and perhaps a CTA. It's a launching point into a more detailed view. What is the content on this card trying to do? Is the main CTA to get to a details view?